# How to get response in a hashmap

Tags: java, api, for-loop, hashmap

this is the response for a particular query.So i need to take each of the values for checking the value.But I am confused to take each of the values in hashmap.For each values like great ,bad the number of persons increase.So how can i get it in a hashmap.

```
{
"Great": [
    {
        "name": "angitha",
        "number": "2",
        "value": "nice"
    },
    {
        "name": "shiva",
        "number": "53",
        "value": "it"
    }
],
"Okay": [
    {
        "name": "anita",
        "number": "2",
        "value": "nice"
    },
    {
        "name": "hansika",
        "number": "21",
        "value": "nice"
    },
    {
        "name": "angitha",
        "number": "24",
        "value": "wow"
],
"Bad": [
    {
        "name": "varun",
        "number": "266",
        "value": "niceee"
    }

]
```

}

I tried this.The feedback size is getting as three(great,okay,bad...).But the values are not getting..Getting null.And I am new to java hashmap.

```
public void comments() throws Exception {
    Map feedback = value.getBody().jsonPath().get();
    for (int i = 0; i < feedback.size(); i++) {
        List comments = (List) feedback.get(i);
        for (int j = 0;  j< comments.size(); i++) {
            Map commentseaching = (Map) comments.get(i);
            Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("name").toString().isEmpty());
            Assert.assertEquals(commentseach.get("value").toString());
            Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("number").toString().isEmpty());
        }

    }
}
```

### My code

This code works perfectly.But here I am taking the values based on get("great") like that.Is there any otherway to reduce the repeation.

```
 public void comments() throws Exception{
    Map feedback = value.getBody().jsonPath().get();
    List comments = (List) feedbackComments.get("Great");
    for(int i=0; i<comments.size();i++){
        Map commentseaching = (Map) comments.get(i);
        Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("name").toString().isEmpty());
        Assert.assertEquals(commentseaching.get("value").toString());
        Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("number").toString().isEmpty());
    }
    comments=(List) feedbackComments.get("Okay");
    for(int i=0; i<comments.size();i++){
        Map commentseaching = (Map) comments.get(i);
        Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("name").toString().isEmpty());
        Assert.assertEquals(commentseaching.get("value").toString());
        Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("number").toString().isEmpty());
    }
    comments=(List) feedbackComments.get("Bad");
    for(int i=0; i<comments.size();i++){
        Map commentseaching = (Map) comments.get(i);
        Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("name").toString().isEmpty());
        Assert.assertEquals(commentseaching.get("value").toString());
        Assert.assertTrue(!commentseaching.get("number").toString().isEmpty());
    }

}
```

Comment: there is an issue in your json data in 28th line, which has to be `}
 ],
 "Bad":`

Comment: I would honestly advise against putting these in a HashMap, but rather a POJO.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach use this [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) lib in order to easy implement your JSON object

**Step 1:** you have to create the models for each Root attribute like BAD,Great and Ok

ex:

```
public class Great{
private String name;
private int number;
private String value;
}
```

**Step 2:** you will need to create Some of arrayList of that model like

```
ArrayList<Great>greatList=new ArrayList()
ArrayList<Bad>badList=new ArrayList()
ArrayList<Ok>okList=new ArrayList()
```

**Step 3:** encode json into Java object like this

```
greatList = gson.fromJson((myJsonResponse.getJSONArray("great")).toString(), new TypeToken<List<Great>>(){}.getType());
okList = gson.fromJson((myJsonResponse.getJSONArray("ok")).toString(), new TypeToken<List<Ok>>(){}.getType());
badList = gson.fromJson((myJsonResponse.getJSONArray("bad")).toString(), new TypeToken<List<Bad>>(){}.getType());
```

this will produce 3 mapped ArrayList of java object you can now use them as java object

However you have a same syntax with all json attributes so i would prefer to use the same class with publication 
for ex:

```
 public class GeneralClass{
    private String name;
    private int number;
    private String value;
    }
```

and then serialize te json object into arrayList of GeneralClass with changing the name of the list only for ex:

```
ArrayList<GeneralClass>badList =new ArrayList();
ArrayList<GeneralClass>okList =new ArrayList();
ArrayList<GeneralClass>greatList =new ArrayList();
```